# Preloading image generated by a script

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to preload an image created by a PHP script with Javascript but I can still see the alt text appear briefly between page loads when I enter a new value in the form field. Is there a way to get the preloading to work in this case?

```
<?php
$text = array_key_exists('text', $_GET)? $_GET['text']: '';
$image_source = 'image.php?text=' . urlencode($text);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">  
      <title>Test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var img = new Image();
         img.src = "<?php echo $image_source; ?>";
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <div><input name="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" /></div>
      </form>

      <div><img src="<?php echo $image_source; ?>" alt="The alt text" /></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information (such as the markup and usage) in your question? Maybe make a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: OK, I added the image element in question.

Comment: That's not really useful. You're saying you're using a bit of code and it's causing a specific problem, but what you have provided is too skeletal to see the problem itself. Have you thought about adding a class and hiding the elements until the `onload` event handler fires? Are you doing the `var img` and markup completely separately, so they're relate? Are you even using handlers? More information needed.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Added a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your html is loading before the javascript does. It makes sense that the alt code shows. You're trying to preload the image AFTER creating the image tag.

What you can do is hide the image tag using css `display:none; visibility:hidden;` and use javascript to unhide it with `window.onLoad()`

Untested example of what i'm talking about. Note that the original javascript is redundant; you already told the browser where to load the image from.

```
<?php
$text = array_key_exists('text', $_GET)? $_GET['text']: '';
$image_source = 'image.php?text=' . urlencode($text);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">  
      <title>Test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload(function(){
            document.getElementById("preload").style.visiblity="visible";
            document.getElementById("preload").style.display="inline";
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <div><input name="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" /></div>
      </form>

      <div><img id="preload" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;" src="<?php echo $image_source; ?>" alt="The alt text" /></div>
   </body>
</html>
```